# Scale locally in blender 2.8

Tags: scale

I know how to scale along local axis (hit `x` or `y` or `z` two times), but how to do it in blender 2.8? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
made question more accurate.

Comment: The same way it is done in Blender 2.79. Hit "S" for scale, "X", "Y" or "Z" for the axis and then "2" for the size.

Comment: If rotation of the object was applied (Object mode > Ctrl+A) or it was rotated in Edit instead of Object mode then its local axes will be equal to global axes in the same way as it was in 2.79- and older versions

Answer (score 2):

Set your Transform orientation to Local

Press S and X, Y or Z

And then 2, Enter

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CmwH1Ks
I did set it to local but it does not work! (still scales along global axis X)

Comment: I think you might have an old version. There have recently been a change to this behaviour. If you still set the Transform orientation to Local and then S, and then X, X (two times) and then 2. But this is the same as 2.79b.

Comment: Thanks! I'll Check!

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have to first rotate your object in *Object Mode*, not *Edit Mode*.
Then, you can scale it locally either in object mode or edit mode.

Scale locally: Press <kbd>S</kbd> the <kbd>X</kbd> , <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> (2 times)

It will not work if you rotate your object in *Edit Mode* first.

If you really need to rotate it in *Edit Mode*, you have to rotate it by adjusting the rotation values, located on the editor right window.

[image]

Then scale locally with S and X, Y or Z (2 times)

Notice that, if you rotate in *Object Mode*, the rotation values will change.

But if you try to rotate in *Edit Mode*, the rotation values does not change.

I'm guessing that in *Object Mode*, there is no faces, only the 3D object

In *Edit Mode*, there is faces geometry and that is why the object's rotation values is not updated.